# Is it possible to set touch bar in F1-F12 mode for a specific app?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I am happy with touch bar in general, but when I am working I want F1-F12 keys when editor is open. Is there a way to make touch bar go in function keys mode when editor becomes active?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes:

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

Select "Function Keys" and hit the plus sign.

Select the app you want to have the function keys display for as default.