# Customise Touch Bar for a specific application

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, touch-bar

So I've been using the MacBook Pro with Touch bar for a week and the Touch Bar seems pretty convenient. However, I haven't found an option to customize the Touch Bar for a specific app.

For example, whenever I code via [jetBrains phpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), I'm used to having the `F[0-12] Buttons` (which aren't displayed in the keyboard anymore in favor of the Touch Bar). I know that if I'm holding the `fn` button, I'll be able to see the `F[0-12] Buttons`. But I want them to be displayed by default without the need to hold the `fn` button.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: This is close to being a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/261456/209426). However, the answers here are good, so it probably shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, you can set your Touch Bar to show the function keys as its default display on an app by app basis.

To do this:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences**
2. Select the **Keyboard** preference pane
3. Click on the **Shortcuts** tab
4. In the left sidebar, select the **Function Keys** option
5. On the right-hand side click on the plus <kbd>+</kbd> button
6. Select the JetBrains PhpStorm app
7. Add the app

Now, whenever you are using the JetBrains PhpStorm app, the Touch Bar should display all the function keys.

Comment: Is this the only way to disable "App Controls" for a certain app? Is there another way, to keep the control strip instead of function keys, but without App Controls, only for a certain app?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work with Spyder, even though I created an app using appify. MacOS is probably looking for something else... in Activity Monitor there are many python processes but no Spyder process.

Comment: Changing the VSCode to show Functions Keys really helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

If you want to REALLY customize your Touch Bar, you'll need [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net).

There is [a short post](https://www.boastr.net/bettertouchtool-touch-bar-customization/) on the official BTT site, linking to [a long blog post on medium.com](https://medium.com/productivity-freak/what-if-you-could-really-customize-your-new-touch-bar-ea42ec66f42c) illustrating Touch Bar customization using BTT.

---

In the interest of link rot prevention, here are a couple of Touch Bar screenshots from the blog post.

Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key for a custom window management bar:

[image]

Customized for the PyCharm IDE:

[image]

There is a lot more, and the above arrangements were customized *by the USER*, not the Pycharm developers or even the BTT developer.

---

Note: I am not affiliated with BetterTouchTool in any way, I just use it and think it's the best quality product of its type—and more people should use it!  :)

Comment: +1 Agreed! Using BTT is an excellent way to do advanced customisations of the Touch Bar. There are other options, but BTT is the leader of the pack, although I've noticed for some it takes a while to suss it out. But it's definitely worth it when they do! :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Monomeeths answer there's another kind of `Touch Bar` configuration that is worth mentioning:

System-native way of configuring elements displayed in `Touch Bar` for specific application is (or at least should be) provided by application itself.

Usually, but not necessarily, this configuration is in `View` menu. A rule of thumb is to look for `Customise Touch Bar...` element in one of status bar menus before you start digging deeper in application preferences.

This screenshot is made for `Safari` browser, however it works the same way for many other applications:

[image: Safari's View menu item]

Sometimes applications bury `Touch Bar` configuration a bit deeper inside their own preferences. For example here's where any `JetBrains` IDE will have it:

[image: PyCharm TouchBar configuration view]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Monomeeth answer if you're using the Jetbrains Toolbox the app will be buried in the Library and you'll have to update the location on each PhpStorm update. If you add the symlink created by the Toolbox it will not work. You need to add the actual `.app` from the location in the Library and it's kind of very deep in there...

The current location in MacOS is `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PhpStorm/ch-0/202.7660.42/PhpStorm.app` but this will change on each update.

There's a related issue to this regarding adding the apps in the dock. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-669

Took me while to find the dam location so hope this helps.