# Switch "Touch Bar shows" per app

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

Some apps (eg IDEs) I like to have Function keys directly shown, but most other apps I like the Quick Actions with Control Strip.

Is there a way to get the Touch Bar to automatically switch between the settings rather than having to manually goto Keyboard prefs?

[image]

Comment: Not that I’m aware of, bettertouchtool is mentioned frequently for this type of thing if you’re open to 3rd party software.

Comment: Isn't there a pref's command line prop that one can write too?

Answer (score 3):

You can designate certain apps to show function keys instead of app controls (in the touch bar) by adding them in `System Preferences` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts` → `Function Keys`.

Related: [Is it possible to set touch bar in F1-F12 mode for a specific app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261456/is-it-possible-to-set-touch-bar-in-f1-f12-mode-for-a-specific-app)